# MVC3 - How to bind a FormCollection to a Model when creating a new database object?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, http-post, model-binding, formcollection

when updating ViewModels via

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, AddressChooserEnum addressChooser, string btnSubmit, FormCollection fc)
{
    var vm = new AddressViewModel(id, addressChooser, bool.FalseString);
    vm.Address = this.repository.GetAddressById(id, addressChooser);
    try
    {
        UpdateModel(vm);
        this.repository.Save();
        return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Customer", new { id = id });
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return View(vm);
    }
}
```

everything works fine. But I can't get creating to work with

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(int id, AddressChooserEnum addressChooser, string btnSubmit, FormCollection fc)
{
    var vm = new AddressViewModel(id, addressChooser, bool.TrueString);
    this.repository.AddAddress(); //What here? It's the simple Add method which needs an Address object.
    this.repository.Save();
    return View(vm);
}
```

I'm trying to create an AddressViewModel with an "empty" Address. But how can I store it with the FormCollection? Can I somehow bind the FormCollection to a new Address object? Then adding should work.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use the form collection.  I would just try to bind straight to the View model.  Without seeing your View it is hard to tell you what your actions should look like.  Check out this article on Model Binding.  It should help! [Model Binding](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Understanding-ASP-NET-MVC-Model-Binding.aspx)

Comment: I tried that already, but got the error, that there is no parameterless constructor for the ViewModel. I added it, but now some things are missing inside the ViewModel. Is there a way to pass the paramterts into the vm-parameter? Like this: public ActionResult Create(int id, AddressChooserEnum addressChooser, string btnSubmit, AddressViewModel vm(id, addressChooser)) {...}